# Eclipse: Gradle source folder migration breaks JUnit test resources

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, junit5, buildship

I refactored an Eclipse project with using Java 11.0.10 to match Gradle's default source and resource folders instead of eclipse's source and resource folders, like this:

```
eclipse          Gradle
src           -> src/main/java
resources     -> src/main/resources
test          -> src/test/java
testResources -> src/test/resources
```

I moved the sources and resources to the folders accordingly.

When I access a test resource within a JUnit test, like `TestClass.class.getResource("/my/package/mytestresource.xml")` it returns `[ProjectFolder]/src/main/resources/my/package/mytestresource.xml` and not `[ProjectFolder]/src/test/resources/my/package/mytestresource.xml`. The test runs over Eclipse's JUnit launcher.

TestClass.java is located in `[ProjectFolder]/src/test/my/package` and the test resource in `[ProjectFolder]/src/test/resources/my/package/mytestresource.xml`.

This worked perfectly before the refactoring.

How can I tell Eclipse and JUnit to merge the output paths together? Or can I tell Eclipse to work with 2 output paths?

Previously the `build.gradle` contained this (which was removed completely):

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs  = ['src']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs  = ['resources']
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs  = ['src', 'test']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs  = ['resources', 'testResources']
        }
    }
}
```

`.classpath` before changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/test" path="test">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/test" path="src">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/test" path="resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/test" path="testResources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-11/">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleclasspathcontainer"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/default"/>
</classpath>
```

`.classpath` after changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/main" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="main"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/main" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="main"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/test" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/test" path="src/test/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-11/">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleclasspathcontainer"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/default"/>
</classpath>
```

I use the following software:

```
Windows 10 Version 2004
eclipse JDT 2021-03
Buildship 3.1.5
Gradle 6.4.1
JUnit Jupiter 5.7.0
```

Comment: So, `mytestresource.xml` is in both `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources`?

Comment: No, it's not, it's only in `src/test/resources`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two workarounds for this issue:

1. Adding the gradle eclipse plugin to the project and manipulating the `classpathentry` in the `.classpath` file of the project:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'eclipse'

   eclipse {
       classpath {
           file {
               whenMerged { 
                   entries.each { source ->
                       if (source.kind == 'src' && source.path.contains('src/main')) { 
                           source.entryAttributes.put("test", "true")
                           source.output="bin/test"
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

or alternatively

2. Re-introducing of the `sourceSets` in the gradle build with Gradle's default source and resource folders.

   ```
   sourceSets {
       main {
           java {
               srcDirs  = ['src/main/java']
           }
           resources {
               srcDirs  = ['src/main/resources']
           }
       }
       test {
           java {
               srcDirs  = ['src/main/java', 'src/test/java']
           }
           resources {
               srcDirs  = ['src/main/resources', 'src/test/resources']
           }
       }
   }
   ```

I'm not sure why this happens with eclipse, but at least it works again.